# JOOQ mysql bitwise

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

We're just switching to using JOOQ in place of standard DAO and straight SQL and I'm trying to convert this SQL to JOOQ context:

products is defined as INT(4) field in MySQL 5.6.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1
FROM table_A WHERE 
    (f1 IS NOT NULL)
    AND (products & 255)
    AND (age <= 180) 
    AND (flag < 1)
ORDER BY f1;
```

JOOQ version:

```
context.selectDistinct(TABLE_A.F1).from(TABLE_A).where(TABLE_A.F1.isNotNull())
    .and(TABLE_A.flag.lessthan(UInteger.valueof(1))
    .and(TABLE_A.age.lessthan(UInteger.valueof(180))
.orderBy(TABLE_A.f1);
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to do the (products & 255) bitwise operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information about bitwise operators / bitwise functions in the [relevant section of the jOOQ manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/bitwise-functions/).

Concretely, using [`DSL.bitAnd()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#bitAnd%28org.jooq.Field,%20org.jooq.Field%29):

```
DSL.bitAnd(TABLE_A.PRODUCTS, 255);
```

See also the related discussion on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/Ml8lLGfIlms/HWGPVjdmIxsJ).

Comment: Why are some functions of JOOQ hidden inside of DSL package?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? `DSL` is a class and it contains all sorts of functions, which you can static-import in your Java classes. In other words, they're not at all "hidden", they're quite exposed :-) See also: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/dsl. I think that it might be useful, though, if bitwise operations were also supported in "infix notation". I'll see that this will be added in jOOQ 3.3: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2848